# Upgrading XCode caused warning for hex Format Specifier

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The following line of code:

```
[colHeader appendFormat:@"%C", 0x2193];
```

throws this warning:

Format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'int'

This started appearing when I upgraded to Xcode 4.4 (upgraded compiler?).  The warning will drive me nuts...any suggestions on how to remove it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest thing is just to cast it, I guess:

```
[colHeader appendFormat:@"%C", (ushort) 0x2193];
```

You can specify that a value is unsigned by appending a "u", e.g., 0x2193u. However, the constant will then be an unsigned int, not an unsigned short, so that won't help you here as you would still get a warning.